# Express post failing on changed parameter with Q service

Tags: node.js, express, q

I have an endpoint in express which returns a promise and passes in a parameter from the req object. This works fine until a the parameter changes.

Here is my endpoint:

```
app.post('/guid', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.body.id;     
  guid.assureGUID(id).then(function(data){
    res.send(data);
  });
})
```

`localhost:3000/guid/1234` would work fine, but when a new parameter is passed in `localhost:3000/guid/1235` the service returns an error.

Here is my guid module

```
var express    = require('express');
var Q          = require('q');
var request    = require('request');
var uuid       = require('uuid');
var util       = require('util');
var tempId;

module.exports = function(app){


var assureGUID = function(id) {
    return getGUID(id);
};


var getGUID = function(id) {

    var deferred = Q.defer();
     console.log(id);

    var getGUIDOptions = {
      url: 'http://third-party-endpoint',
      method: 'POST',
      json: {
        "guid": id
      }
    };

    request(getGUIDOptions, function(err,resp,body){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      if(200 !== resp.statusCode){
        console.log(new Error('failed to retrieve GUID, status='+resp.statusCode));
        return;
      }
      if(!('object'===typeof body && 'string'===typeof body.guid && body.guid)){
        console.log(new Error('failed to retrieve GUID, resp: '+util.inspect(resp,{depth:null})));
        return;
      }
      deferred.resolve(body.guid);
      app.locals.guid = body.guid;
    });

  return deferred.promise;

};



return {
        assureGUID: assureGUID
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what getGUIDOptions contains?

Comment: it contains the url and header type for the http request

Comment: I can't see anything in your code that would indicate why `1234` would work and `1235` wouldn't work.  I'm going to guess it's something to do with your endpoint.  Have you checked to see what responses you're getting from it with both IDs?  Also, what type of error are you getting?

Comment: it's really just a problem with whatever I hit the enpoint with the first time will work...and keep working. Once the id parameter changes though it fails. I suspect it's something with the way I'm returning the promise each time